# I'm facing "Failed to compile values file." error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

**I'm facing an error in this code can someone help me that what is the issue when I run my app the following error comes from that screenshot I posted below .**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Animation top,bottom;
            TextView wlc,dev;
            ImageView logo;
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            try
            {
                this.getSupportActionBar().hide();
            }
            catch (NullPointerException e){}
    
            top= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.animations);
            bottom= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.animt);
            wlc=findViewById(R.id.textView);
            dev=findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            logo=findViewById(R.id.logo);
            wlc.setAnimation(top);
            dev.setAnimation(bottom);
            logo.setAnimation(top);
    
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please tell us how is this question related to Firebase?

Comment: @AlexMamo no its not related to fire base its a simple code I'm trying to add some animations in my activity